# Change Session Id On Authentication in weblogic

Tags: session, weblogic

For weblogic 9, how to set Change Session Id On Authentication?
For 11g, It is available under console.

does such a property available in weblogic 9 ?
is it possible to set in weblogic.xml or implement by code ?

-Thanks.